# For each x, I observe A and know P(C). What can I say about E(A|C)?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes, noise

For each subject *x* in a population,

- I observe *x*'s age, *A(x)*.
- I can calculate the probability that *x* has some property of interest *c*, $P[C(x) = 1]$, where C(x) is a binary variable indicating whether x has the property of interest (the measurement for *c* is quite noisy, which is why I know only the probability that *x* has this property, and do not know *C(x)* exactly. I can assume that the measurement error is independent of *A*).

I know the marginal distributions of age and *c* across the full population.

Can I calculate the expected age of those who have *c* across the full population, $E[A|C]$?

**Update:** I might have figured out a solution to this, though I would love a second opinion as to whether this works.

1. By definition of expectation, $E[A|C] = \sum_kA_k*P(A_k|C)$, where the summation is over all observed ages.
2. By Bayes rule, this equals $\sum_kA_k\frac{P(C|A_k)P(A_k)}{P(C)} = \frac{1}{P(C)}\sum_kA_k*P(C|A_k)*P(A_k)$
3. I can estimate the value of $P(C|A_k)$ for each $k$ by simply averaging the values of $P(C(x))$ across all subjects whose age equals $A_k$.
4. I can substitute these $P(C|A_k)$ into 2 to find $E[A|C]$.

Comment: Welcome to our site! There's no need to add a thanks to your question - to thank an answerer, you can upvote their answer (once you have enough reputation) and "accept" (green uptick) the answer that best satisfies your needs (though it's best to wait a few days in case more answers come later).

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by your second bullet point? My first impression was that by "the probability that x has some property of interest C" you meant either P(C), or at least the probability conditional on sex since you have stated that is observable in your first bullet point. But judging from the rest of the question this was not your intention. (I'm also a bit confused by "the measurement for C is quite noisy, which is why I do not know C exactly" - it seems as if you are switching between an event and a random variable.)

Comment: @Silverfish, I clarified the phrasing and added a possible solution. Would love to hear your take on it.

Comment: Just to make this super-clear, $C(x)$ is intended to be a binary/dummy variable for property of interest, which is coded as 0 if the $x$ does not have the property and as 1 if $x$ does? (Always a good idea to define these things clearly when they're introduced to the reader...)